# Facebook Comments Box: Restrict the ability to comment under certain circumstances

Tags: facebook

I am trying to add the Facebook comments box to my site.

The problem I am having is that I want to disable the ability to post under various circumstances. An example of this would be "If the user is not logged in: Show all of the comments so far, but instead of the ability to add comments, display a "Sign Up to Comment" button.

Right now, the best idea I can come up with is to just remove the whole comment box and replace it with the aforementioned button thus getting rid of all of the existing comments. This will not work for my purposes, because there would be no incentive for the user to sign up using this method.

I have looked into trying to create two versions of the comment box: one with the permission to post, and one without. However, I did not seem to find any way to do this.

Now I am just completely out of ideas.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook comments plugin is limited as to what it can do.  All of the options are documented on the developer site.  I don't see where you could specify how it is displayed like you want.  I would suggest building your own facebook app to do comments, then you have full control over how comments are displayed.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Yeah, I thought there would be a lazy way around writing an app.

Comment: Yeah, most developers are 'lazy'. That's why we try to write reusable code all the time.  :)